# How to convert classes into simple arrow functions

Tags: function, class

hey guys I am trying to convert the class into a simple arrow function:

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
     super();
     this.state={
       email:"",
       password:""
     }
   }
}
```

can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) to use state inside function based component:

```js
const App = () => {
 const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
 const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
}
```